# How can Tor Browser Bundle for OS X access my keychain?

Tags: password, login, keychain

I would like Tor Browser Bundle for OS X to work with my keychain, so that after filling out logins and passwords on a website one time, I would never have to do it again later. This works with safari, but it doesn't with the Vidalia packed aurora (firefox) browser. What settings should I change?

Comment: What is the point of using Tor when you are going to login to websites? If you just want to avoid packet-sniffing on the network, you could use HTTPS or a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You can't. Firefox always uses it's own store for passwords and will never access the Mac OS X keychain at all. You either have to manually copy your credentials into Torbrowser/Firefox windows or use a third party software like 1Password that integrates across browsers.

Be aware that if you use a login on a website that hasn't been created over tor there is a good chance you're giving up your anonymity by yourself. Tor cannot protect you from posting your identity (by logging in with a username and password) by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to make Firefox save passwords in OSX keychain, but nevertheless you can use Tor with browser that supports keychain. You can configure Safari or Google Chrome to use Tor.

- Just look how configured proxy in bundled Firefox [Firefox > Preferences > Advanced > Network > Settings]:

[image]

- Configure proxy in Google Chrome the same way.

Now you will be able to store passwords in keychain while using Chrome.